# Moving return of exponential moving average -- choice of alpha

Tags: time-series, exponential-smoothing

I have a time series with an exponential moving average and I want to calculate a moving return of the EMA over the last m periods (something like a smoothed moving return).

Let's say:

Y(t) is the value of the time series at time period t

S(t) is the value of an EMA of Y at time period t

Now R(t) is the return of the EMA over the last m time periods:

R(t) = S(t) / S(t-m) - 1

My question is: how many time periods should the EMA calculation use for a given m?
Precisely, if the EMA is calculated using S(t) = alpha * Y(t) + (1-alpha) * S(t-1) and alpha is set by 2/(N+1), then how should N depend on m?

I'm assuming that N should be sufficiently less than m to prevent 'overlap' of Y values that are used in the calculation of S(t) and S(t-m).

Any theories or best practices about this?

Comment: Your question is unclear at the moment - perhaps you could edit it to make it clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

N itself is often set in an arbitrary manner that makes sense for the application. Frankly the alpha = 2/(N+1) is also somewhat arbitrary, http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc431.htm suggests instead doing an optimization that minimizes the mean squared error. (Nevertheless, alpha = 2/(N+1) seems to be fairly standard practice.)

So as to how n should depend on m, or vice versa, I say try to find something that makes sense given your particular data and that will help with interpreting your results. I wouldn't worry about overlap too much, as it's not like the data is independent--that's why you do the EMA in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, but even if the data is not independent, when you want to calculate the EMA return from t-m to t, you would ideally not want to have the EMA at t include information before t-m.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a rather complex problem. There are a few directions you can look into. One way, typically recommended in the forecasting literature, is to optimize for the forecasting error.

If you have a specific application in mind you can define your own cost function to optimize.

A different view on this is to look at the EWMA as a state space model, then the problem is equivalent to setting up an appropriate Kalman filter which you can do with MLE, see for instance [Time Series Analysis by State Space Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198523548)

There are other directions you can go, but I think this will give you an idea...